# java code doesn't work in fragment activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-videoview

I try to create an application in android platform with 3 fragments

When I try to input some java code inside the fragment class, i have always this error: 
`java.lang.NullPointerException`

For example, with a simple button to change view:

```java
package com.test;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class creation extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.creation, container, false);

        final Button ok = (Button)getView(). findViewById(R.id.button3);
        ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Create new fragment and transaction
                Fragment newFragment = new mesvideos();
                // consider using Java coding conventions (upper char class names!!!)
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
                // and add the transaction to the back stack
                transaction.replace(R.layout.creation, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                // Commit the transaction
                transaction.commit(); 


        }
    });
return root ;
}
```

Or with a `VideoView` :

```java
mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
             mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +
                        "/" + R.raw.presentation));
             mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
             mVideoView.requestFocus();
```

Comment: paste the full stack trace (copy the part of logcat where the error exists)

Comment: The error tells you the exact line in which it happens. There is in 99% of all cases a `.` in that line. The thing before the `.` is `null`. In your case `getView()`

Answer (score 3):

Rather than just saying that you encounter NullPointerException, please specify the full stacktrace or tell us on which line of your code the NPE occurs.

FWIW, your

```
final Button ok = (Button)getView(). findViewById(R.id.button3);
```

should probably be

```
final Button ok = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button3);
```

I suspect since you have only just created the root view and haven't returned/set it yet, getView() will return null

PS. Your class name "creation" is nonstandard. Java class names should start with a capital letter, and if your class extends Fragment then it's customary to let the class name end with "Fragment". E.g.: "CreationFragment".